# use SetupGetInfDriverStoreLocation function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, msdn, setupapi

```
BOOL SetupGetInfDriverStoreLocation(
  _In_      PCTSTR               FileName,
  _In_opt_  PSP_ALTPLATFORM_INFO AlternatePlatformInfo,
  _In_opt_  PCTSTR               LocaleName,
  _Out_     PTSTR                ReturnBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD                ReturnBufferSize,
  _Out_opt_ PDWORD               RequiredSize
);
```

How can I call this function if I have FileName as:

```
TCHAR  FileName[MAX_VALUE_NAME];

where #define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common pattern in the Windows API; you give the function a buffer and the size of the buffer (often as a character count) and the call will fail if the buffer is too small.

```
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383
TCHAR fullpath[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
BOOL result = SetupGetInfDriverStoreLocation(TEXT("NameOfMyFile.inf"), 0, 0, fullpath, MAX_VALUE_NAME, 0);
if (result) MessageBox(0, fullpath, 0, 0);
```

Your buffer is very large (MSDN says "The maximum supported path size is MAX_PATH") so it should be able to hold any .inf path but the function is designed so you can first call it with a NULL buffer:

> To determine the size of the return buffer that is required to contain
>   the fully qualified file name of the specified INF file in the driver
>   store, call SetupGetInfDriverStoreLocation and set ReturnBuffer to
>   NULL, ReturnBufferSize to zero, and supply RequiredSize.
>   SetupGetInfDriverStoreLocation will return the required buffer size in
>   RequiredSize.

I'd call this the "peek, allocate, get" pattern. If there is a chance the data might actually change then you should call it in a loop until the "get" call succeeds.